# блок мигалка на js

Tags: javascript

Как написать чтобы блок мигал разными цветами интервалом 1 секундой?

Answer (score 4):

Нижеприведённый код генерирует каждую секунду случайный цвет и задаёт его фону нашего блока.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("bl");
setInterval(function() {
  var red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256).toString(16);
  var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256).toString(16);
  var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256).toString(16);

  el.style.background = "#" + red + green + blue;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="bl">Ваш блок</div>
```